# SQL - using String concatenation, how can I exploit this procedure?

Tags: sql-injection

I have a simple Stored Procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[test]
@str varchar (100)
AS
BEGIN
select * from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee] where JobTitle like '%' + @str +'%'
END
GO
```

Given this type of code, in what ways can I exploit it?

I've always been told that exploits of the sort of

```
exec test ''' ''; truncate table [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee];--'
```

Should work, but now is the 1st time I got a chance to try it practically and it does not work.

The explanation I was given was that

```
''' ''; truncate table [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee];--'
```

When concatenated with the query becomes

```
select * from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee] where JobTitle like '%' + ' ' ; truncate table [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee];-- + '%'
```

So, the `SELECT` query will execute with the jobtitle searching for any character followed by a space. The `;` terminates the where condition and then the truncate table statement executes. Where am I going wrong? I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> where JobTitle like '%' + @str +'%'

This is not an SQL-injection vulnerability. It isn't injecting content into the query from a higher level of control such as a string `EXEC` or a call from C#.

There is an injection error here, however it is not SQL-injection. The concatenation that is being done is a search term into a `LIKE` query pattern. Metacharacters in `LIKE` patterns are `%`, `_` and, in SQL Server, `[` (non-ANSI-standard).

The upshot of this is that if anyone does a search for, say, `50%`, they will get results that contain the substring `50` and not only ones that contain `50%`. Use of `[` can also probably result in a syntax error. That's undesirable, but it doesn't allow any of the traditional security attacks that SQL injections do.

To fix LIKE-injections, you need to nominate a custom LIKE-escape character, and use it to replace any LIKE-metacharacters, eg:

```
SET @liketerm = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, '!', '!!'), '%', '!%'), '_', '!_'), '[', '![');

... WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%'+@liketerm+'%' ESCAPE '!';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify @bobince's answer (accept his answer, not mine!), this is not a SQL injection concern because the statement is not dynamically *built* using your @str variable -- instead it is *passed* to a static statement.

If the procedure instead read:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = 'select * from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee] where JobTitle like ''%' + @str + '%''';
    EXEC @sql;
END
```

...you would be open to an injection using terms similar to those which you typed above.  Typically, these sorts of constructs tend to happen in the application layer, such as a PHP or ASP app (not singling those out):

```
// NON-LANGUAGE-SPECIFIC PSEUDO CODE
var searchTerm = Request.Form("searchField");
var sql "select * from [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee] where JobTitle like '%" & searchTerm & "%'";
var results = db.execute(sql);
```

One common place you do see such code is in multi-field search procedures, where the user can supply a number of values and each value is compared against a different field or requires a different join.  The SQL is then built to only add those WHERE or JOIN clauses if and when a term is given (which *can* provide a more performant query).  You should take considerable care to properly sanitise your input if you need to do this in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs that you are giving will not work.

You will need to close the '%' character first and then throw in your query. Your end query should be :

where JobTitle like '% **str%';query to append -- '**

Hope this helps.

Comment: AFAIK, the % operator does not need to be in pairs.  `like '%abc'` should work without any issue, and it does